# ARDUINO Gravando dados no cartão SD pelo ethernet shield

Tags: c, arduino

Boa noite

Estou querendo fazer o arduino uno gravar dados em um cartão SD
Eu Não tenho o modulo para cartão SD para o Arduíno

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu tenho o modulo ethernet shield, que tem uma entrada para cartão SD

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é possível usar o ethernet shield para gravar dados no cartão SD por meio de sua entrada para cartão? Um exemplo pronto me ajudaria bastante!

Comment: Tenta ver nesta [comunidade](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) que é mais focada no Arduíno.

Comment: Esse leitor na ethernet funciona da mesma forma que a versão standalone, voce pode, por exemplo, usar a biblioteca SD com ambos. De qq forma, perguntas sobre hardware e suporte [não estão no nosso escopo](/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Bacco entendo que hardware não seja o foco aqui, entretanto a inserção dos dados será feita via software,  não ?

Comment: @MagicHat enquanto não tiver um código com problema no corpo da pergunta, junto da descrição do erro, não ;)

Comment: Aí concordo que faltou...x/